# failed to return after waiting 10 seconds - UIWebView loadHTMLString

Tags: ios, uiwebview

when I load a `UIWebView` with the following code:

```
NSString *helpText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lorem Ipsum"];

[self.helpWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body stlye=\"background-color: transparent;\"><div align='justify' style=\"color: #000000; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: %fem;\">%@</div></body></html>", fontSize, helpText] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

I get this error, but only the first time when a `WebView` is loaded in my app:

```
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

And the text will load, but only after 10 seconds. But the UI is blocked for 10 Seconds. When I navigate through the app, other ("later") `UIWebViews` will load immediately and it is not related to this specific `UIWebView`, i.e. if I got to `UIWebView` A and then to `UIWebView` B, A will load after 10 seconds of UI blocking and B will load instantly. IF it starts with B and then goes to A, B will load after 10 seconds and A will load instantly. So, only the first `UIWebView` which is loaded creates a problem.

And I really only load the html above. Some douzen of characters, no JScript, no big tables, no funny html stuff. It will even block the UI and report the error message if I load a blank HTML-String.

I have not set any delegate stuff or something like this. I created the `UIWebView` in Interface Builder, connected it to the header via property and I am using `loadHTMLString` to get content into.

Important: I can currently only use the Simulator, so I cannot predict, whether this is only a Simulator issue. If you know it, please let me know. At the moment, I cannot test at a real device. The Simulator should not go into this error because of ressources however. I have a current MacBook Air and almost no extra programs installed ("clean installation" of Mac OS X Lion).

Another Point: The only reason why I use `UIWebView` is that I need full justification for the text. If this would work any other way, would help me too. At least from Android development, I know that there is no other way than a `WebView`.

Comment: No one any idea on this topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is solved with the update from today (iOS 6.1 SDK) and I also think it is related to the simulator. I think it is about interfering outgoing requests from skpaymenttransaction and other UIWebView... I am not sure about anything, however...